# Get rid of duplicate content in JSON file?

Tags: php, json

I accidentally appended several (same!) json files into a single json file using `fopen("folder/".$filename.".json", "a");`.A really big mess..Anyone know of a solution to 'clean' those files and get rid of the duplicate content?

Now, each of my json files look similar to this (no linebreaks though):

```
{"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,
"previous_cursor_str":"0","lists":[{"id":...
...
}]}
{"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,
"previous_cursor_str":"0","lists":[{"id":...
...
}]} 
{"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,
"previous_cursor_str":"0","lists":[{"id":...
...
}]} 
etc.
```

In fact, the structure in every file is always the same. Every block begins with `{"next_cursor":...`

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this (preferably in PHP)?

Thank you!

Comment: You could count open braces (+1) and closed braces (-1) until you got back to 0, and then split your records accordingly.  Simple work with `substr()` and `strpos()` will get you there.

Comment: thanks @Brad. Sounds promising! I'll try this!

Comment: Using a JSON formatter like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://www.onlinejsonformatter.com/ might be easier than counting braces.

Comment: How would a JSON formatter help me split the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start reading the file character by character and parse the string of characters read until that point with json_decode, if it returns a value different from NULL then you have your valid JSON that you can use to overwrite the file content.

```
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r');
    $content = '';
    while ( !feof($fp) ) {
       $content .= fread( $fp, 1 );
       if ( json_decode($content) !== null ) {
         fclose($fp);
         file_put_contents( $file, $content );
         break;
       }
    }
}
```